# audio encryption over python socket

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, security, encryption, tcp

i have a client and server. but i am currently carrying out the encryption in the client side what could be wrong with my code since i am unable to make a conversation with the other client. when i remove the encryption i am able to communicate. here is code at the client side...................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
class Client:
def __init__(self):
    self.window=Tk()
    #self.window.title("mulll")
    self.window.title("VOICE OVER LAN")
    self.firstname=Label(self.window,text="ENTER PHONE NUMBER").grid(column=3,row=0)
    self.first=Text(self.window,height=3,width=30)
    self.first.grid(column=5,row=1) 
    self.btn7=Button(self.window,text="1",height=4,width=8).grid(column=0,row=3)
    self.btn8=Button(self.window,text="2",height=4,width=8).grid(column=1,row=3)
    self.btn9=Button(self.window,text="3",height=4,width=8).grid(column=2,row=3)
    self.btn10=Button(self.window,text="4",height=4,width=8).grid(column=0,row=4)
    self.btn11=Button(self.window,text="5",height=4,width=8).grid(column=1,row=4)
    self.btn12=Button(self.window,text="6",height=4,width=8).grid(column=2,row=4)
    self.btn13=Button(self.window,text="7",height=4,width=8).grid(column=0,row=5)
    self.btn14=Button(self.window,text="8",height=4,width=8).grid(column=1,row=5)
    self.btn15=Button(self.window,text="9",height=4,width=8).grid(column=2,row=5)
    self.btn16=Button(self.window,text="0",height=4,width=8).grid(column=1,row=6)
    self.btn14=Button(self.window,text="FINANCE",height=4,width=14).grid(column=3,row=3)
    self.btn15=Button(self.window,text="RECEPTION",height=4,width=14).grid(column=3,row=4)
    self.btn16=Button(self.window,text="PROCUREMENT",height=4,width=14).grid(column=3,row=5)
    self.btn14=Button(self.window,text="CALL",height=4,width=14).grid(column=3,row=6)
    self.btn15=Button(self.window,text="DECLINE",height=4,width=14).grid(column=3,row=7)
    self.key=Fernet.generate_key()
    self.fernet=Fernet(self.key)
    with open("E:/python/key.key", "wb") as filekey:
            filekey.write(self.key)
    with open("E:/python/key.key", "rb") as filekey:
            self.key=filekey.read()
    receive_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.receiver).start()
    self.window.mainloop()
def receiver(self):
    self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    while 1:
        try:
            self.target_ip = input('Enter IP address of server --> ')
            self.target_port = int(input('Enter target port of server --> '))

            self.s.connect((self.target_ip, self.target_port))
            break
        except:
            print("Couldn't connect to server")  
    chunk_size = 1024 # 512
    audio_format = pyaudio.paInt16
    channels = 1
    rate = 20000
    # initialise microphone recording
    self.p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    self.playing_stream = self.p.open(format=audio_format, channels=channels, rate=rate, output=True, frames_per_buffer=chunk_size)
    self.recording_stream = self.p.open(format=audio_format, channels=channels, rate=rate, input=True, frames_per_buffer=chunk_size)   
    print("Connected to Server")
    # start threads
    receive_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.receive_server_data).start()
    self.send_data_to_server()
def receive_server_data(self):
    while True:
        try:
            data = self.s.recv(1024)
            with open(data,"rb") as encfile:
                data=encfile.read()
            decrypted=self.fernet.decrypt(data)
            self.playing_stream.write(data)
        except:
            pass

def send_data_to_server(self):
    while True:
        try:
            data = self.recording_stream.read(1024)
            with open("E:/python/key.key", "rb") as filekey:
                self.key=filekey.read()
            with open(data, "rb") as file:
                data=file.read()
            encrypted=self.fernet.encrypt(data)
            self.s.sendall(data)
            self.window.mainloop()
        except:
            pass
```

client = Client()

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate the `unable to make a conversation`, log and compare the sent and received data. What the `generate_key` does? If generating a random, then are you sure the client and server are using the same value?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).